# Access Azure Data Lake Analytics Tables from SQL Server Polybase

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql, sql-data-warehouse

I need to export a multi terabyte dataset processed via Azure Data Lake Analytics(ADLA) onto a SQL Server database.

Based on my research so far, I know that I can write the result of (ADLA) output to a Data Lake store or WASB using built-in outputters, and then read the output data from SQL server using Polybase.

However, creating the result of ADLA processing as an ADLA table seems pretty enticing to us. It is a clean solution (no files to manage), multiple readers, built-in partitioning, distribution keys and the potential for allowing other processes to access the tables.

If we use ADLA tables, can I access ADLA tables via SQL Polybase? If not, is there any way to access the files underlying the ADLA tables directly from Polybase?

I know that I can probably do this using ADF, but at this point I want to avoid ADF to the extent possible - to minimize costs, and to keep the process simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Polybase support for ADLA Tables is still on the roadmap and not yet available. Please file a feature request through the [SQL Data Warehouse User voice page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse).

The suggested work-around is to produce the information as Csv in ADLA and then create the partitioned and distributed table in SQL DW and use Polybase to read the data and fill the SQL DW managed table.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'll file a feature request.

Is there a way to see Data Lake file system metadata about U-SQL tables? It'd be nice to see the size, location, number of files, folder partitions etc.

Comment: The files that contain the table data are in the `/catalog` folder. You can use the `usql.*` catalog views to find the guids to find the location and partition information.